# Python: regex to recognize document header

Tags: python, regex

I have parsed a document into separate sentences, but some of the parsed sentences also contain the document's headers. This means a few sentences look like this:

> Blah bla blah some text . **2 Year 2011 Company name , Company
>   disclaimer Date 5 january 2011** Blah blah blah text continues .

Now I want to remove the headers (if present) and split the string in two (one sentence before the header, other sentence after the header.

The dates in the header differ, but it always...

- starts with a page number, followed by 'Year' and the year's number;
- ends with: 'Date' + (int) + (string) + (int).

Would there be a regular expression to recognize this header and delete it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with:

```
\d+\sYear\s\d{4}[\w\s,]+?Date\s\d+\s\w+\s\d{4}
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/tU0kO8/3)

however depends on text content, there could be fragments which also match. So maybe a longer example will be needed.

Comment: Thanks for this great answer! However, it doesn't seem to work because the header also contains a comma (forgot to mention that, sorry - changed my post now). How could I account for this?

Comment: @Leon_NL I updated answer. I added `,` to character class `[\w\s,]` so it can match word character, whitespaces or commas. Strill if there is non-header fragment, which this regex could match, maybe it is necessary to make regex more specific

Answer (score 1):

You can use `re.sub` providing an empty string as `repl` parameter.

```
re.sub("\d+ Year \d{4}.*Date \d{1,2} (january|february) \d{4}", "", your_sentence)
```

Take a look at [re.sub](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub) for more details.

you can also make use of [Pythex](http://pythex.org/) to test the regular expression patterns.